# restlet 2.2, configure jackson format support

Tags: restlet, fasterxml

Restlet 2.2 uses the fasterxml jackson library to support json serialization.

There are other data bindings supported by jackson, other than json, and included with the restlet 2.2 distribution.  As such, many jars are loaded at program start time.  Here is the full list:

- com.fasterxml.jackson.annotations.jar
- com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jar
- com.fasterxml.jackson.csv.jar
- com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jar
- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxb.jar
- com.fasterxml.jackson.smile.jar
- com.fasterxml.jackson.xml.jar
- com.fasterxml.jackson.yaml.jar

How do I configure jackson, or restlet, so that it does not attempt to load the formats that I'm not interested in using?  e.g. I have no interest in smile, yaml, or csv but if I don't include these jars I get a class not found exception when my server starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that it's a Restlet issue but I made work Restlet and Jackson with not all these jars.

If you only want to use Jackson for the JSON format, you can add the following jar files:

- com.fasterxml.jackson.annotations.jar: Jackson annotation
- com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jar: Jackson core
- com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jar: Jackson data binding
- com.fasterxml.jackson.smile.jar: Jackson smile support

Hope it will help you.
Thierry

Comment: I'm using JSON and XML. Yes, it helps.